# Perl function: accept hash, array, or scalar as parameter

Tags: perl, reference, parameter-passing

I have the following sub-routine.

```
 sub Function{
   my $ref = \($_[0]);
   if(ref($ref) eq 'SCALAR'){
   . . .
   }
}
```

I am trying to get it to work such that passing a list, scalar or hash to it, it converts that into a reference and depending upon whether that reference is of type `ARRAY`, `SCALAR` or `HASH`, different actions are performed.

It could be called as

```
Function(%a)
Function($a)
Function(@a)
```

How can I make `$ref` be a reference to whatever is passed to the `Function`? My current approach isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a prototyped function. Although Perl 5 prototypes are a total mess, they can be used quite well in this case. As I understand them the prototype

```
sub Function (\[$@%]) {...}
```

should solve your problem, and the reference be in `$_[0]`.

The big disadvantage is that the variable you pass *has* to start with the `$`, `@`, or `%` *character*, so you can't call `Function` with a constant argument directly:

```
 Function(1)
```

fails, but

```
 my $temp = 1;
 Function($temp)
```

works.

---

Your approach failes, because `@_` *is* a list, and all elements are scalars.

Comment: I understand why `$_[0]` failed previously. Thanks! 

I am using that `Function()` recursively and it is failing when I use the above prototype with the error `Function called too early to check prototype` when trying to recurse.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon then `use subs 'Function'` at the beginning of the module/file to force prototype checking

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon Yes, but this scalar `$_[0]` is a *reference* to the original argument. You can view the contents with `print Data::Dumper::Dump $_[0]`

Comment: Dumper prints it right. The entire array. It is a ref to the original arg. But when I do `ref($_[0])`, it says `SCALAR`, even though it is an array I passed.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon For testing purposes, I used this one-liner: `perl -MData::Dumper -e'sub Function (\[$@%]) {print $_[0], "\n"; print Dumper $_[0]} @x = (1, 2); Function(@x)'` Output: `ARRAY(0x8a5bcec) $VAR1 = [1, 2];`. And `ref` *is* `ARRAY`.

Comment: Wow. My fault here. I was calling the function as `&function()`. I never thought that'd make a difference. Thanks. This works perfectly. But adding that & before the function call makes it behave weirdly. I don't really know why.

Comment: The `&function` syntax is *very* bad (and Perl 4-y): it disables prototype checking and makes the `@_` array visible to the called function. Only use if this specific behaviour is desired

Answer (score 6):

```
Function(%a)
Function($a)
Function(@a)
```

You can't do what you are asking. There is no way inside `Function` to determine whether an array or a hash was passed, because, in fact, you can't pass an array or a hash to a sub in the first place. You can only pass a list; the hashes and arrays are converted to lists in the sub calls above.

You should pass a reference to the function in the first place:

```
Function(\%a)
Function($a)
Function(\@a)
```

Then you can check what it is easily:

```
sub Function {
  my $param = shift;
  if (not ref $param) {
     ...
  } elsif (ref $param eq 'HASH') {
     ...
  } elsif (ref $param eq 'ARRAY') {
     ...
  }
```

Comment: I understood that :)
Thanks. But there is a way to pass the array or hash-ref, even if array or hash is passed by user. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12583728/759019)

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon It's really quite hackish though. Why can't you pass a reference instead of a list? Are you working with legacy code? If so, I could see why you would want amon's solution, but, in new code, it is not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check to see if the argument passed in is a reference and act accordingly?

```
sub gimme_a_ref
{
  my $arg=shift;

  if(ref $arg ne ref "")
  {
    return $arg;
  }
  else
  {
    return \$arg;
  }
}
```

Comment: `given (ref $arg) {return $arg when [qw(ARRAY HASH CODE SCALAR)]; default {return \$arg}}` is *far cleaner*.

Comment: or: `sub gimme_a_ref { my $arg = shift; return ref $arg ? $arg : \$arg }`

Comment: `my $arg = shift; ` If I was passing a hash to the function, wouldn't the scalar $arg just contain the first key?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon - Well, what do you want to have happen if `@_ > 1`? Since `=>` is treated the same as a comma, the subroutine wouldn't know if you intended to pass the elements of `@_` as an array (that is not an array ref) or as a hash (that is not a hash ref) (with the exception of passing in an odd number of arguments, of course).

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon - It sounds as though you might want to separate your functionality: one subroutine to take a list of arguments that will be treated as a hash, another to take a list of arguments that will be treated as an array, etc.

Comment: I do agree. This probably isn't the right way :). Data::Dumper seems to do the above, when passed ref or not. I was trying to look into some way to do the same.

Comment: Yeah. The above does work. It is just that once it gets into the function, doing `ref($_[0])` always returns `SCALAR`, if I directly pass a hash or array to it. With hash-refs and array-refs, this works right.

Comment: Another alternative would be to pass along an argument indicating whether the remaining arguments are to be taken as an array or a hash. Or you could pass in one hash reference, say `{type=>'hash',args=>{key1=>"value1",key2=>"value2",...}}` or `{type=>'array',args=>['arg1','arg2',...]}`.